# Numbers whose digits are sorted in every base

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which natural numbers $n$ have digits sorted largest to smallest in every base $b$
from $1$ to $n$? The table below shows that $n=1,2,3,4$ each satisfy this
property, but $n=5$ does not, because neither $5_2 = 101$ is sorted,
nor is $5_3=12$.

***Q***. Is it the case that only $n=1,2,3,4$ have non-increasing digits, left-to-right, in every base?

| $n$ | $b$ | digits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $1,2$ | $11,10$ |
| $3$ | $1,2,3$ | $111,11,10$ |
| $4$ | $1,2,3,4$ | $1111,100,11,10$ |
| $5$ | $1,2,3,4,5$ | $11111,\color{Red}{101,12},11,10$ |

Comment: For large enough $n$, in base $(n-2)$, $n = 12_{n-2}$.

Comment: @peterwhy: That settles it, as it is for $n=5$ that $5_3=12$ first occurs. Thanks!